# How to change the border color of a Material-UI Box/Tab component to black?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Box and Tab component from Material-UI in my React app, and I want to change the border color to black while still keeping it as a divider. I've tried setting the borderColor property to 'black' and 'divider' in the sx prop, but it still shows up as blue. I'm using Material-UI version 5. How can I change the border color to black?

This is what I have right now:

```
<Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider'}}>
  <Tabs value={value} onChange={handle} aria-label="tabs">
    <Tab label="First Tab" />
```

Image blue right now but want the divider line and text black:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your styles in `<Tabs/>` component and not in the `<Box/>` component. There are two ways you can change Tabs text and indicator line colour.

1️⃣ If the colour you need is one of the `primary` or `secondary` colours. Because `textColor` and `indicatorColor` props of `<Tabs/>` only accept these options. Then you do this

```
<Tabs
    textColor="secondary"
    indicatorColor="secondary"
  >
```

2️⃣ If you want a custom colour then you use `sx` prop of `<Tabs/>` and target the classes mentioned below

```
<Tabs
   sx={{
     "& .MuiTab-root.Mui-selected": { color: "red" },
     "& .MuiTabs-indicator": { bgcolor: "red" }
    }}
  >
```

Comment: when i add these styles then save they apply but when i refresh the page only the indicators style sticks not the selected why is this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. We need to combine two classes to make it work for the default tab. I will work now even if you refresh the page. Thanks.